# Which hoster should I use for my private react app?

Tags: reactjs, deployment

I would like to deploy my react app. So far I've seen many solutions, but they all require a public git repository.

I don't want to publish my source code and I would like to password protect my react app, so that only people with the right password can test the app.

I could use http://www.passportjs.org for the authentication, but which hoster should i choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private git i prefer using gitlab.com, gitlab has CI/CD feature to deploy to AWS Service. And you can protect your app via IP list in your app!

So: If you want private your repo, use gitlab private repo, and deploy it to AWS, and secure your app via IP list.